# How to print in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a prolog source that looks like this

```
road(arad, zerind, 75).
road(arad, sibiu, 140).
road(arad, timisoara, 118).

depth_first([[Goal|Path]|_],Goal,[Goal|Path],0).
depth_first([Path|Queue],Goal,FinalPath,N) :-
    extend(Path,NewPaths), 
    append(NewPaths,Queue,NewQueue),
    depth_first(NewQueue,Goal,FinalPath,M),
    N is M+1.

extend([Node|Path],NewPaths) :-
    findall([NewNode,Node|Path],
            (road(Node,NewNode,_), 
            \+ member(NewNode,Path)), % for avoiding loops
            NewPaths).

run:-
    write('Enter the ORIGIN City: '),read(S),
    write('Enter the Destination City: '),read(D),
    write('Type of search: '),nl,
    write('1. depth_first search 2. exit'),nl,
    write('Enter your option:'),nl,
    read(X),choice(X).
    choice(X):-X=:=1, 
    depth_first([[S]],D,P,C), writeln([P]).
```

So when I do depth_first([[arad]],zerind,P,C). it prints as P = [zerind, arad],
C = 1 . but when I run it using run. it just print some numbers.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: "it just print some numbers". What numbers?

Comment: something like this "[[_12102]] true ."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost correct. Just that in the choice predicate, in addition to taking the option variable X, you also need to carry over the origin city S and the destination D.

```
run:-
    write('Enter the ORIGIN City: '),read(S),
    write('Enter the Destination City: '),read(D),
    write('Type of search: '),nl,
    write('1. depth_first search 2. exit'),nl,
    write('Enter your option:'),nl,
    read(X),choice(X, S, D).

choice(1, S, D) :- 
    depth_first([[S]],D,P,_), writeln([P]).
```

Now it works as it should directly calling depth_first.
Does my answer reply to your question ?